# How to require mixed element to be non-empty in RelaxNG?

Tags: xml, schema, relaxng

I'm having trouble finding a solution to the problem of disallowing an empty mixed element, i.e. I want to force my mixed element to be non-empty. The following question addresses this perfectly for simpler elements: [Define an element as non-empty in RelaxNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195885/define-an-element-as-non-empty-in-relaxng)

Say I have the element `text` that is **mixed** content (i.e. an interleave with text) that may contain elements `bold`, `italic`, `underline`. I could define this in RelaxNG as:

```
<element name="text">
 <mixed>
  <zeroOrMore>
    <ref name="bold" /> 
  </zeroOrMore>
  <zeroOrMore>
    <ref name="italic" /> 
  </zeroOrMore>
  <zeroOrMore>
    <ref name="underline" /> 
  </zeroOrMore>    
 </mixed>
</element>
```

What I want to disallow is first and foremost `<text></text>`, which the above doesn't do of course. Ideally I also want to disallow any other whitespace-only value (`<text> </text>`). Anything else should be valid (also constructs like `<text><bold>blah</bold></text>`). I toyed around with the following but that didn't even validate a simple `<text>blah</text>` instance:

```
<element name="text">
 <interleave>
  <data type="string">
    <param name="pattern">.+</pattern>
  </data>
  <zeroOrMore>
    <ref name="bold" /> 
  </zeroOrMore>
  <zeroOrMore>
    <ref name="italic" /> 
  </zeroOrMore>
  <zeroOrMore>
    <ref name="underline" /> 
  </zeroOrMore>    
 </interleave>
</element>
```

Any RelaxNG experts around who can shed a light on this?

Comment: I suppose `<text><bold>         </bold></text>` should also be disallowed, right? Whatever the answer to what I just asked, I don't see how you can do it without stepping out of Relax NG to use some additional validation facilities like Schematron. Your 2nd code block with `data` violates [this constraint](http://relaxng.org/spec-20011203.html#string-sequences). AFAIK there's no simple fix.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I want to apply the solution recursively. I was already fearing I'd hit the limits of RelaxNG with this. Perhaps looking into additional validation schemes like Schematron is not a bad idea indeed.